# Lua not allowing global variables in a table

Tags: lua, davinci-resolve

I have some code in Lua:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
amount = 0 --math.random(0, 54000)
bgItem = mediaPool:AppendToTimeline({ {
    mediaPoolItem = clip[1],
    trackIndex = 1,
    recordFrame = 216000,
    startFrame = amount,
    endFrame = amount+total,
    mediaType = 1
} })[1]
```

Having `amount` as `0` works perfectly fine, but when I set it to `math.random(0, 54000)` it gives an error: `attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'amount' (a nil value)`. I am extremely confused as to why it works differently when it's set normally and when it's set by the output of a function.

Comment: `math.random()` seems to return `nil`. What happens if you do not call `math.randomseed()`? Also, I would recommend to declare all variables as `local`, unless you *must* use globals.

Comment: Indeed, `local amount = math.random(0, 54000)` might fix the problem

Comment: `math.randomseed(os.time())` should be invoked only once, at the program start.

Comment: ```math.ramdom(1, 5400)``` will fix it, because with arguments the first argument has to be an integer above 0. See the Lua Reference.

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi - even `math.random(-4, -2)` works correctly for me.

Comment: @ESkri You are of course right - It is not 'above 0' it is 'except 0' - Thanks

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi - `math.random(0, 2)` works for me too (in both Lua 5.4 and LuaJIT).  What Lua version does not accept 0 as parameter in `math.random`?  Please give a link to Lua Reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [koyaanisqatsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11740758/koyaanisqatsi) for the comment, the issue lied in the specific function I was using to get a random number. Lua's `math.random()` function cannot take in `0` as an argument. This was solved by simply changing it to `1` instead.